# Outlook emails moving from deleted items back to the inbox

Tags: exchange, outlook

I have a very strange problem. On one of the machines running Outlook 2003 (using Exchange 2000), something will 'randomly' move all the items from the **Deleted Items** back to the **Inbox** folder. I can find no rules, macros, or archive settings that would be causing this.

Has anyone ever seen something like this, or know if this is a known bug?

Comment: Some info to update your Q with: how many users are running off the exchange server and what kind of traffic are they pushing around; i.e. # of messages and what ball-park total byte size of incoming email each day?

Answer (score 1):

Check the 'conflicts' or 'sync error' folders (you may have to switch to full folder view in Outlook. Maybe your antivirus is cusing sync errors between outlook and exchange. Don't forget about their antivirus on your server.

Also, are you sure it's exchange **2000**? That one is getting a bit long in the tooth (i.e. old).

Comment: Yeah, it is quite old..  :(   I don't actually see a conflicts or sync errors folder in Outlook.

Comment: OK, maybe you have hit a limit in the exchange 2000 server database? Is the exchange 2000 database healthy? Is there any other glitches going on with moving email?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will have to check with the Exchange admin on this.